# Twitch related: Twitch Video player

Tags: javascript, php, twitch

I am having a problem with twitch video player.

When I add the video player to the website and define the username without a PHP var it loads like it should but as soon as I add a var from PHP it doesn't load the stream from twitch.

This is how the code looks like with out the php Var (JS):

```
<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v2.js"></script>
<div id="{PLAYER_DIV_ID}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: 480,
        channel: "channel", 
        //video: "{VIDEO_ID}"       
    };
    var player = new Twitch.Player("{PLAYER_DIV_ID}", options);
    player.setVolume(0.3);
</script>
```

This is the code with the PHP var (the one that won't work.

```
<script src= "http://player.twitch.tv/js/embed/v2.js"></script>
<div id="{PLAYER_DIV_ID}"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
        width: '100%',
        height: 480,
        channel: "<?php $channel ?>", 
        //video: "{VIDEO_ID}"       
    };
    var player = new Twitch.Player("{PLAYER_DIV_ID}", options);
    player.setVolume(0.3);
</script>
```

There might be a stupid questions. This is the first time I add "PHP" to a "JS" script like this, so I might do something wrong.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with your php code -

You should do

```
<?php echo $channel?>
```

OR just

```
<?= $channel ?>
```

Comment: I feel so stupid atm.. haha that i diden't think about echo'ing it out, Thanks

Comment: glad I could help :)